# Make Windows 10 "remember" language in applications

Tags: windows-10, input-languages

System language is English. In app1 I need English, in app2 I type in Spanish. I often switch from app1 to app2. It's too depressive to switch languages when switching apps.
Is it possible in some way make Windows 10 "remember" language which I use in different applications?